# border-image not working in mozilla

Tags: html, css, mozilla

I am applying `border-image` using `css` like below:

```
 border-image: url('/assets/btn-border.png') 10 10 10 10;
```

It is working fine for Chrome but in Mozilla the border isn't appearing.

I tried to use `.gecko` to that class but that didn't work.

What's the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the style for firefox

```
border-style: solid;
border-image: url('/assets/btn-border.png') 10 10 10 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

add

```
border-style: solid;
```

should works